# What is the proper way to terminate a script using start-stop-daemon?

Tags: bash, start-stop-daemon

I am using a start-stop-daemon to make a INIT script for my script. I am using `--make-pidfile` cause my script doesn't make its own pid. I can start my script using start and pid file generates with appropriate PID. But the stop function doesn't work. I am getting return code 0 with `--oknodo` and 1 without it. If I do

```
ps -ef | grep perl
```

and

```
cat /home/me/mydaemon/run
```

I always see the same PID. I can terminate the script using

```
kill -15 PID.
```

But not with the stop function of my init script.

What is the proper way to stop my process?

As per start-stop-daemon manual,

> --stop Checks  for  the  existence  of  a specified process.  If such a process exists, start-stop-daemon sends it the signal  specified by 
>   --signal,  and exits with error status 0.  If such a process does not exist, start-stop-daemon exits with error status  1  (0 if  --oknodo 
>   is  specified).  If  --retry  is  specified,  then start-stop-daemon
>   will check that the  process(es)  have  terminated.

I didn't find find any documentation for `--signal` itself. Like how to specify `--signal` if I want to send a SIGTERM.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myd
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Description:       Diitalk daemon for sending push notifications
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON="/home/me/mydaemon/myd"
NAME="myd"
DESC="My Daemon"
HOMEDIR=/home/me/mydaemon/run
PIDFILE="$HOMEDIR/$NAME.pid"
USER=me
GROUP=me
SHM_MEMORY=64
PKG_MEMORY=8
DUMP_CORE=no

case "$1" in
  start|debug)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE \
                --exec $DAEMON || log_failure_msg " already running"
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
  stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
        start-stop-daemon --oknodo --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
                --exec $DAEMON
        echo $?
        log_end_msg 0
        ;;
```

Comment: The argument to `--signal` is either going to be the signal name (`TERM`) or the signal number (`15`) I assume but the man page seems to indicate that `TERM` is the default. What about your stop command there doesn't work? What's the return code of that call?

Comment: I am getting 0 with --oknodo

Comment: And without `--oknodo`? 1? Is your process still running? Is the pid in the pidfile correct?

Comment: yes with and without --oknodo my process still runs. I checked my pid file and it always contains the right pid (the pid of my script). I can terminate my script using kill -15 <pid> though

Comment: Does your daemon run with the name in `$DAEMON` or does it exec/fork/etc. and change names? If you run with `−−test` what does it say it is going to do? Does adding `--verbose` to the call say anything useful?

Comment: it runs with something like  /usr/bin/perl $DAEMON. Didnt get anything adding --test and verbose. I updated my post.. please check

Comment: The only thing I can think to suggest at this point is to run `start-stop-daemon` under `strace` (or similar) and see what it is actually doing (and not doing). `strace -o /tmp/daemon.strace -f start-stop-daemon ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the --exec that I used for matching the process name. As per the start-stop-daemon documentation :

```
   -x, --exec executable
          Check  for  processes  that  are  instances  of  this executable
          (according to /proc/pid/exe).
```

In my case as my script is Perl script, /proc/pid/exe is symlinked to  /usr/bin/perl; therefore the exec couldnt match the process name. I removed the exec so that it matches only the PID. Now I can properly stop my process.

Comment: Going purely by pid is, theoretically, unsafe. You should probably use `-x /usr/bin/perl` or similar to at least attempt to be sure it is the right thing you are killing.